# dataTable prevent column resizing when filtering data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a dataTable which I am filtering dynamically once the table has been initialized.  I have a JS function that takes 1 arg which is the string to be used as the filter.  I'm setting the filter on the table using...

```
oTable = fnFilter(strFilter);
```

This works fine, but after the table is filtered the columns seem to re-size themselves.
I already have bAutoWidth set to false, so I'm not sure what else I can apply that will prevent the columns from resizing.  I want the sizes I have defined in the th tags to remain no matter what data is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bAutoWidth` is just a flag indicating whether dataTables should calculate the widths automatically. Setting it to false is an optimisation feature, see the [**docs**](http://datatables.net/usage/features) :

> Enable or disable automatic column width calculation. This can be
>   disabled as an optimisation (it takes some time to calculate the
>   widths) if the tables widths are passed in using aoColumns.

But the browser will still expand / shrink the `<td>`'s according to their content. This is how tables work. To achieve what you want, the trick is to use `sScrollX` and `aoColumns` like this :

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
  sScrollX: "100%",
  aoColumns: [ 
    { "sWidth": "50px" },
    { "sWidth": "50px" },
    { "sWidth": "50px" },
    { "sWidth": "50px" },
    { "sWidth": "50px" }
  ]
});
```

This gives a table with the width of 250px, each column 50px - regardless of the content. `sScrollX` forces dataTable to maintain the width both of the table *and* the columns.

See this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/MW8Ku/ demonstrating that the above apporach also is working *after* a call to `fnFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer referring to `sScrollX` and `sWidth` is using legacy DataTables API.  Since v 1.10+, the syntax is:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "scrollX": true,
  "columns": [
    { "width": "50px" },
    { "width": "50px" },
    { "width": "50px" },
    { "width": "50px" },
    { "width": "50px" }
  ]
});
```

**Ref:**

- [scrollx](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX)
- [columns](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width)